# Installing appium on macOS sierra 10.12.3

Tags: android, ios, automation, appium

I bought a new mac machine and need to install appium from scratch.

I just went through few docs from google but each site had different instructions.

Can you please guide me through how to install all required software to run appium on Mac machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check whether java is installed or not(If you want to use java as programming language for appium scripts).
2. You need xcode for simulators and ios SDK.Install latest xcode from AppStore.
3. Install homebrew by using following command in terminal.To run this command user should be admin.

   ```
   ruby -e “$(curl -fsSL  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)”
   ```
4. Install node.js by using the below command in terminal.

   ```
   brew install node
   ```
5. Install appium by using below command.

   ```
   npm install -g appium
   ```
6. Install Carthage by using below command.

   ```
   brew install carthage
   ```
7. Install xcode command line developer tools using the command.

   ```
   xcode-select --install
   ```

Comment: I get an error message in step 3 as `-e:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `“' for main:Object (NameError)`

Comment: try installing with sudo before the command

Comment: change the " symbols.Type the command instead of copy paste

Comment: I did that, but there was no changes seen on the terminal