# Launch and run appium in Mac

Tags: ios, automation, appium

I just installed Java and appium as explained in the link below:

[Installing appium on macOS sierra 10.12.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43222122/installing-appium-on-macos-sierra-10-12-3/43224442#43224442.)

Now how do I launch and run appium to start writing code or tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing appium through the terminal as mentioned in your previous question, You can launch tha appium server simply by running the command as below:

```
appium
```

If you want to specify particular port on which the appium should be started you can mention the port number as in below command.

```
appium -p 8056
```

Here 8056 is the port number on which you want to run the appium.
For knowing various commands and arguments available try the below command

```
appium help
```

Comment: Thanks. After I start the appium server, what should I do? I dont see any screen for typing or any appium GUI

Comment: Appium wont have any GUI from appium 1.6 after you started appium server u need to write scripts in the IDE based on the language you want to work with(Eclipse for java)

Comment: So i need to install an IDE, example eclipse? Which is the best version to install? After I intsall an IDE, what is the next step?

Comment: based on the platform(Android or ios) you want to automate you have to write the scripts

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it going with the following:

```
Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node     /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js
```

Comment: should I copy paste the entire command in my terminal?