# Error: The desired capabilities must include either an app or a bundleId for iOS

Tags: ios, appium-ios

I am using mac OS X 10.12, Appium server 1.5.3 , xcode version 8.3. If I run the doctor then it shows the appium is installed correctly.

```
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic starting ###
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode is installed at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode Command Line Tools are installed.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ DevToolsSecurity is enabled.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Authorization DB is set up properly.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Node.js binary was found at: /usr/local/bin/node
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ HOME is set to: /Users/nishamendon
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to: /Users/nishamendon/Library/Android/sdk
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ JAVA_HOME is set to: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ adb exists at: /Users/nishamendon/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ android exists at: /Users/nishamendon/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ emulator exists at: /Users/nishamendon/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic completed, no fix needed. ###
info AppiumDoctor 
info AppiumDoctor Everything looks good, bye!
info AppiumDoctor
```

But, if I start the appium server, and I try to launch the inspector I am getting an error unable to start Inspector with the below log.

```
    [iOS] Error: The desired capabilities must include either an app or a bundleId for iOS
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
    at IosDriver.validateDesiredCaps (lib/driver.js:409:14)
    at IosDriver.callee$0$0$ (lib/basedriver/commands/session.js:14:8)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at enqueueResult (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:185:17)
    at Promise.F (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.export.js:30:36)
    at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:184:12)
    at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at Object.runtime.async (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:209:12)
    at IosDriver.callee$0$0 [as createSession] (lib/basedriver/commands/session.js:8:46)
    at IosDriver.createSession$ (lib/driver.js:40:16)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at enqueueResult (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:185:17)
    at Promise.F (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.export.js:30:36)
    at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:184:12)
    at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at Object.runtime.async (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:209:12)
    at IosDriver.createSession (lib/driver.js:110:19)
    at AppiumDriver.createSession$ (lib/appium.js:121:43)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at enqueueR
esult (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:185:17)
    at Promise.F (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.export.js:30:36)
    at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:184:12)
    at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at Object.runtime.async (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:209:12)
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/saikrishna321/PageObjectPatternAppium/issues/8) could help you. Please, also format your question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier thanks .. Will try

Answer (score 1):

The regenerator error occurs because xCode 8 works only with appium 1.6 +.

You can refer: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6845

Comment: Thank you. Will try this

Answer (score 1):

Add the desired capabilities for the app path as (for eg.)
DesiredCapabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/foldername/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appname.app");

Also, you can open appium inspector of 1.5.3 just by opening appium GUI, keeping iOS icon selected and tapping inspector icon (don't tap 'Launch' in GUI) after starting appium (1.6+) server in terminal.
Refer: https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-launch-appium-inspector-on-appium-1-6-0-beta2-as-there-is-no-appium-app-file-for-that-beta/12448/16

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the capabilitiy "app" or "bundleId".Because in your case it is not able to know which app it should launch.

```
capabilities.setCapability("app","path of your .app file");
```

Appium 1.5.3 is not compatible with xcode 8+. If you are already installed appium through terminal then launch the appium through terminal by running the command.

```
appium
```

This command will start the appium server.Don not use appium 1.5.3.

Refer the below link to know how to launch and run the appium from terminal after installing appium 1.6+

[Launch and run appium in Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245891/launch-and-run-appium-in-mac/43246230#43246230)

Comment: Thanks. Will try this.

Comment: It worked but now another problem. Now when i run the inspector i get "Encountered internal error running command:Error: Installing com.xxxx.remoteOn.NonProd failed" :(Tried the below steps:
    brew uninstall ideviceinstaller
    brew uninstall libimobiledevice
    brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
    brew link --overwrite libimobiledevice
    brew install ideviceinstaller
    brew link --overwrite ideviceinstaller
along with  "sudo chmod -R 777 /var/db/lockdown/"still the same problem.Now i wm using xcode 8.3.2 on appium 1.5.3.And trying to automate an ios app on phone 10.2

Comment: which appium version you are using and which is the os version of your simulator or device