# An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Command failed: ideviceinstaller -u

Tags: java, ios, iphone, selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

I m trying to launch Safari Browser on iPhone 6 using Appium along with Selenium.

Please find the configuration details I m using.

```
iPhone : 6
MAC : 10.12.4
Xcode : 8.3.2
Appium : 1.5.3
```

Below is the code I have written to start driver.

```
desCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
desCapabilities.setCapability("platformName","iOS");
desCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6");
desCapabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
desCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "10.3.1");
desCapabilities.setCapability("app", "com.apple.mobilesafari");
desCapabilities.setCapability("udid", "*******");
public static RemoteWebDriver iOSDriver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://" + nodeUrl + ":" + nodeUrlPort + "/wd/hub"), desCapabilities);
```

While Running the test, it throws the below error. Kindly provide the suggestions to solve this issue.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred 
while processing the command. Original error: Command failed: ideviceinstaller 
-u <udid> i./Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/build/SafariLauncher/SafariLauncher.app(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 8.13 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision:'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09' 
System info: host: 'MacBook.local', ip: '****', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch:'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.4', java.version: '1.7.0_71'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the appium version 1.5.3 which is not compatible from xcode 8 and ios 10. Update your appium to 1.6 or above.

To know how to start the appium server after installing appium 1.6 refer the below link:

[Launch and run appium in Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245891/launch-and-run-appium-in-mac/43246230#43246230)

Comment: One more doubt..
To launch the default browser(Safari) in iPhone using Appium, do we need   AppleID..?
Since I have only free account of Apple ID. Is this fine..?

Comment: I have build-ed an app in real device using xcode and using this can able to launch that app on real device.

Comment: You can launch already installed app by using bundleid of that app.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, I have already installed Appium 1.5.3.
And now I have installed Appium 1.6.3 using the command (npm install appium@1.6.3).

Comment: When I Type 'Appium' in Terminal, It displayed "command not found".

Comment: is appium installation from terminal successful

Comment: I think it is installed,
I got the below message in terminal

    npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/msubramaniam/package.json'

    npm WARN msubramaniam No description
    npm WARN msubramaniam No repository field.
    npm WARN msubramaniam No README data
    npm WARN msubramaniam No license field.

Comment: it is issue with installation try installing properly

Comment: mail me @ saipawan.lingutla@gmail.com we can talk