# How to transfer from UIAutomation( on Xcode 7) to XCUITest( on Xcode 8)

Tags: java, xcode8, appium-ios

I used appium on iOS 9.3 with Xcode 7 and used a lot of execution scripts on my code.For example:

`executeScript("UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().sliders()[0].value()");`

But now, I upgraded to Xcode 8 with iOS 10.3, the execution is not working. Do you have any idea to resolve this ? Can I still use `excuteScript()` and change scripts from UIAutomation to XCUITest ? If can, can you provide the table of actions transfer from UIAutomation to XCUITest ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade appium to 1.6.This is not an GUI appication like appium 1.5.3.

Refer the below link for installation :

[Installing appium on macOS sierra 10.12.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43222122/installing-appium-on-macos-sierra-10-12-3/43224442#43224442)

Comment: I'm using appium 1.6. But my problem still haven't resolved. Any ideas ?